# nodes stopping because of Bus error: 10

Tags: cardano-node

All I can find online is that Bus error: 10 means it's trying to reach a memory space that isn't there.  The testnet/preprod/mainnet nodes start up fine but stop shortly after with either Bus erro:10 or sometimes I get segmentation fault: 11.  What is going on?

Comment: I have same problem. Running MacBook Pro. The node worked fine for a long time but then suddenly when started it gets the ”bus error: 10” or the ”segmentation fault”. Tried update to latest 1.35.7 cardano node and also reinstall the whole node. Doesn’t work.
Would really appreciate some help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Was having the same issue, building version `8.1.2` with GHC `9.2.8` instead resolved for me.